# accesing javascript executed inside index.html in any of my component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I generated some device UUID using https://github.com/biggora/device-uuid/blob/master/sample/index.html
and the id generated can be seen in my console. However in order to do this I generated it in public index.html file .How can we pass it to any our component in reactjs .

```
<script>

 var du = new DeviceUUID().parse();
var dua = [
    du.language,
    du.platform,
    du.os,
    du.cpuCores,
    du.isAuthoritative,
    du.silkAccelerated,
    du.isKindleFire,
    du.isDesktop,
    du.isMobile,
    du.isTablet,
    du.isWindows,
    du.isLinux,
    du.isLinux64,
    du.isMac,
    du.isiPad,
    du.isiPhone,
    du.isiPod,
    du.isSmartTV,
    du.pixelDepth,
    du.isTouchScreen
];
var uuid = du.hashMD5(dua.join(':'));
console.log(uuid);
</script>
```

Comment: You could try `window.uuid`?

Comment: Yes.  It worked.  How can we get the device's name with which it has been accessed?

Answer (score 1):

you can store this value in document variable like

`document.uuid = uuid`

then you can use it in the react by accessing document.uuid

Answer (score 0):

Store in Local storage 
 like

```
window.localStorage.setItem('uuid ', uuid );
```

and get from Local Storage whereever you need

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file in the public folder (config.js for example) and put inside your treatment for the UUID:

```
var du = new DeviceUUID().parse();
var dua = [
    du.language,
    du.platform,
    du.os,
    du.cpuCores,
    du.isAuthoritative,
    du.silkAccelerated,
    du.isKindleFire,
    du.isDesktop,
    du.isMobile,
    du.isTablet,
    du.isWindows,
    du.isLinux,
    du.isLinux64,
    du.isMac,
    du.isiPad,
    du.isiPhone,
    du.isiPod,
    du.isSmartTV,
    du.pixelDepth,
    du.isTouchScreen
];
var uuid = du.hashMD5(dua.join(':'));
window.config = {
    UUID: uuid
}
```

then pass it to your index.html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
```

then to use your UUID inside your components, you have to call it like:

```
const UUID = window.config.UUID
```

for information: you can visit this link [using-the-public-folder](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder) to know when you should use the public folder